# Installing liferay via ssh

Tags: ssh, installation, liferay

I have installed liferay on my local machine and it works well. Now I wish to install liferay on a remote server via ssh. How do I go about this. I have downloaded the installation files and copied them onto the server. When I run startup.sh everything seems to be fine, but a look at catalina.out shows the error: Could not find or load main class ???-Djava.awt.headless=true???. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Liferay do you want to install? Do you have the same version of JDK on local and remote machine?

Comment: I have the same version - 6.2 of liferay. The local machine does not really matter, I can do away with it since it was just for tests. The problem is that I cannot run liferay on the remote machine where I have copied the downloaded file for installation.

Comment: Server: java version "1.7.0_72"; Local: java version "1.8.0_66"